# Is anyone using Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Desktops or Workstations at home?

Tags: linux, rhel

I consider using RHEL for my dissertation, on my Thinkpad T430. 
I've been using Linux (mostly Ubuntu, Debian) for the last decade but I'm curious about RHEL
since it seems to be used a lot outside academia.
I think it might be good to accustom myself with it.

Has anyone used it on their home computer, are there any major benefits
or drawbacks compared to the free Linux versions?

Comment: Server distributions tend to be out of date, even more than say Debian stable. Also, the packages that are available tend to be quite limited. Both reasons why an individual might want to consider something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have in the past used RHEL and CentOS (a binary compatible clone built from RHEL sources) for my desktops/laptops. The issue I regularly ran into was that the driver support was not as bleeding edge in these distributions so my newer hardware was not always recognized or usable.

Since I work on RHEL servers every day, I want to stay as close as I can to RHEL on my workstations. Fedora is the community based testbed in which all versions of RHEL are based on after all. This is why I eventually moved to Fedora. I have a very close platform to my RHEL servers and can still have bleeding edge drivers and software.

Comment: Thank you, albeit being curious about commercial Linux versions I decided to continue using Debian.. :)